# How to solve this obscure and excessively localised problem with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame wherein I want to give a score to each of the element in a distinct values column.

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
|            A                  |             B                 |      Distinct Values         |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
| ['a', 'b', 'c']               |   ['a', 'b']                  |  ['a', 'b', 'c']             | 
| ['c', 'b', 'e', 'a']          |   ['b', 'e', 'a']             |  ['a', 'b', 'e', 'c']        |
| ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']          |   ['a', 'b', 'c']             |  ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'c']   |
| ['a', 'b', 'c']               |   ['a', 'd', 'c']             |  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']        |
|                               |                               |                              |  
+-- ----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------+




           ( NO. of times that element has occurred in A and B)
Scoring =  ----------------------------------------------------
               (Total number of elements(Distinct Values))
```

This is how it would look like after scoring:

```
+------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|            A           |         B          |      Distinct_Values_with_scoring             |
+------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| ['a', 'b', 'c']        |   ['a', 'b']       |['a':2/3, 'b':2/3, 'c':1/3]                    | 
| ['c', 'b', 'e', 'a']   |   ['b', 'e', 'a']  |['a':2/4, 'b':2/4, 'e':2/4, 'c':1/4]           |
| ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']   |   ['a', 'b', 'c']  |['a':2/5, 'b':2/5, 'd':1/5, 'e':1/5, 'c':1/5]  |
| ['a', 'b', 'c']        |   ['a', 'd', 'c']  |['a':2/4, 'b':1/4, 'c':2/4, 'd':1/4]           |
|                        |                    |                                               |  
+-- ---------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

How can I go about solving this problem in pandas?

```html
d = {"A":[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'e', 'a'],
          ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], 
     "B": [['a', 'b'],['b', 'e', 'a'],['a', 'b', 'c'],
           ['a', 'd', 'c']],
     "Distinct Values": [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'c'],
           ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]}
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: do you want `dict` or `list`? because `['a':2/3, 'b':2/3, 'c':1/3] ` not valid in python

Comment: Yea, I doesn't matter. It can be anything until unless I am getting the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because columns `A` and `B` are both lists, you can just add them together to get the total elements.  Then use `Counter` in a dictionary comprehension to get the count of each letter, and divide each count by the total number of unique letters (determined by the length of the set).

```
from collections import Counter

# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'e', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
    'B': [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'e', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'c']]
})

# Solution.
>>> df.assign(
    Distinct_Values_with_scoring=
    df['A']
    .add(df['B'])
    .apply(lambda x: {k: v / len(set(x)) for k, v in Counter(x).items()})
)
              A          B                       Distinct_Values_with_scoring
0     [a, b, c]     [a, b]  {'a': 0.6666666666666666, 'b': 0.6666666666666...
1  [c, b, e, a]  [b, e, a]          {'c': 0.25, 'b': 0.5, 'e': 0.5, 'a': 0.5}
2  [a, b, d, e]  [a, b, c]  {'a': 0.4, 'b': 0.4, 'd': 0.2, 'e': 0.2, 'c': ...
3     [a, b, c]  [a, d, c]         {'a': 0.5, 'b': 0.25, 'c': 0.5, 'd': 0.25}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def func(x):
    d = {}
    ele = x['A'] + x['B']
    for i in x["Distinct Values"]:
        d[i] = ele.count(i)/len(x["Distinct Values"])
    return d

df["Distinct_Values_with_scoring"] = df.apply(func, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can find distinct length and all values. Then you can apply value counts on all_values divide by distinct length

```
data['all_values'] = data['A'] + data['B']
data['distinct len'] = data['Distinct Values'].apply(len)

data[['all_values', 'distinct len']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.value_counts(x[0])/x[1], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am waiting for my model to run, so here's an over-killed answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[['a','b','c'], ['c','b','e','a'],['a','b','c']],
    'B':[['a','b'],['b','e','a'],['a','b','d','e']]
})

(df['A'].explode().reset_index()
               .merge(df['B'].explode().reset_index(),
                      left_on=['index','A'],
                      right_on=['index','B'],
                      how='outer')
    .set_index('index')
    .assign(occur=lambda x: x.notna().sum(axis=1),
            value=lambda x: x.ffill(1)['B'])
    .assign(total=lambda x: x.groupby('index')['occur'].transform('count'))
    .assign(score=lambda x: x['occur']/x['total'])
    .drop(['A','B','occur','total'], axis=1)
    .groupby('index').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('value')['score'].to_dict())
)
```

Output:

```
index
0    {'a': 0.6666666666666666, 'b': 0.6666666666666...
1            {'c': 0.25, 'b': 0.5, 'e': 0.5, 'a': 0.5}
2    {'a': 0.4, 'b': 0.4, 'c': 0.2, 'd': 0.2, 'e': ...
dtype: object
```